How to increase the size of the legend box in Julia Plots?
I am using Plots in Julia.
When I join two graphs into the same plot, the legend marker goes outside the legend itself. I've used legendfontsize, but it would be hard to see the words if I reduced it enough for the marker to stay inside.
What else can I do? Is there a way to enlarge the legend box or decrease only the legend marker (not the markers of scatter)?


not a true answer, but if you don't care about the box around the legend you can "fix" this by setting foreground_color_legend = nothing

Also not a true answer, but this has been an issue with Plots for a while (see https://discourse.julialang.org/t/resize-legend-box-in-subplots-for-plots-jl/36141/8). I'd recommend switching to Makie for Julia plots - lots more customizable than Plots tends to be. For example, here's how you'd do the fix in Makie: https://docs.makie.org/v0.21/reference/blocks/legend.
